# Как сделать чтобы при вводе определенной команды роли что-то делали? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Например пользователь вводит команду /fight @blue @red и бот пишет @Blue vs @Red. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def fight(ctx, 1c, 2c):
    await ctx.send(f"{1c} vs {2c}")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def fight(ctx, member_one: discord.Member, member_two: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"{member_one} vs {member_two}")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]